# Best practice when trying to set a javaScript variable from a jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

One of the senior developers in the team sent around an email on best practice to get a variable from a jsp into javaScript. He recommended declaring a global variable eg config and then using script tags in the jsp and then jQuery's extend to add the variable into the config object. He also said the worst way to do it was to set it into the html and read it with a jquery selector.

Now I think the opposite! I thought having script tags all over your page was quite bad for page load times and actually you should set variables like this into the HTML using the data attribute and read them out with jquery selectors as and when you need them.

However I've had several disagreements with this person and don't want to seem like I'm disagreeing for the sake of it so thought I'd double check before challenging him :)

Comment: Why would putting a global variable in a script tag result in "having script tags all over your page"? False dilemma.

Comment: Well when this is done in multiple jsps that are included all over the place then you will.

Comment: And how does it differ from putting values in html tags all over the place? 
You might consider using Ajax requests to retrieve the values.

Comment: I thought the browser stopped parsing the html when it hits a script tag so ultimately having script tags all over the place would slow down page load, if we just have data-attributes there is no break in parsing the HTML. Also I would agree we should AJAX them and it alot of cases we do but there are a few uses cases we have where that is not suitable.